# Prolog Logic Puzzle Failure

Tags: prolog, zebra-puzzle

I am attempting to solve the logic puzzle found here: https://www.braingle.com/brainteasers/teaser.php?id=23826&op=2&comm=1#c

These are the clues:

> 1. The flowers were purchased in the following order: tulips, the flowers for the office, the purple flowers, the roses for the park, and the white flowers bought by Julia.
> 2. Bethany loves flowers but is allergic, so she would never have them indoors.
> 3. It rained on Wednesday and Friday, because of this, the wedding and birthday party had to be moved indoors.
> 4. Amy bought her flowers after Rachel, but before Kristen.
> 5. Rachel needed something more to add to her office, so she chose peach flowers to match her curtains.
> 6. On Wednesday the only purple flowers available at the flower shop were daisies.
> 7. The pink flowers were bought after the carnations, but before the lilies.
> 8. The flowers for the birthday were bought after the flowers for the office, but before the flowers for the wedding.

I have attempted to implement this in prolog with the following code:

```
/*
Use a nested predicate of flowers to store the solution

flowers(
  f(Woman1,Flower1,Color1,Place1,Day1),
  f(Woman2,Flower2,Color2,Place2,Day2),
  f(Woman3,Flower3,Color3,Place3,Day3),
  f(Woman4,Flower4,Color4,Place4,Day4),
  f(Woman5,Flower5,Color5,Place5,Day5)
).
*/

/* The flowers predicate contains a given flower X */
has(X,F) :- F=flowers(X,_,_,_,_).
has(X,F) :- F=flowers(_,X,_,_,_).
has(X,F) :- F=flowers(_,_,X,_,_).
has(X,F) :- F=flowers(_,_,_,X,_).
has(X,F) :- F=flowers(_,_,_,_,X).

/*Defines that X occurs on an earlier day than Y */
before(X,Y,F) :- append(_,[X|Tail], F), append(_,[Y|_],Tail).


solve(F) :-
  F = flowers(A,B,C,D,E),
/*clue 1 */
  A = f(_,tulips,yellow,_,monday),
  B = f(_,_,_,office,tuesday),
  C = f(_,_,purple,_,wednesday),
  D = f(_,roses,_,park,thursday),
  E = f(julia,_,white,_,friday),
/* Clue 2 --> Look @ clue 3, Bethany can only have flowers in backyard or park */
  has(f(bethany,_,_,backyard,_),F), 
  has(f(bethany,_,_,_,park,_),F),
/* Clue #4, Amy before Kristen, Rachel before Amy */
  before(f(amy,_,_,_,_),f(kristen,_,_,_,_),F),
  before(f(rachel,_,_,_,_),f(amy,_,_,_,_),F),
/* Clue #5 */
  has(f(rachel,_,peach,office,_),F),
/* Clue #6 */
  has(f(_,daisies,purple,_,wednesday),F),
/* Clue #7, pink before lillies, carnations before pink */
  before(f(_,_,pink,_,_),f(_,lilies,_,_,_),F),
  before(f(_,carnations,_,_,_),f(_,_,pink,_,_),F),
/* Clue #8 */
  before(f(_,_,_,birthday,_),f(_,_,_,wedding,_),F),
  before(f(_,_,_,office,_),f(_,_,_,birthday,_),F).
```

This doesn't seem to be working. I believe the problem is either with my code in defining a flower occurs before another one, but I am not sure if that is the issue and how to remedy it. Also, I think there's an issue with saying that Bethany bought flowers for backyard or park (NOT wedding, bday, or office).

Here is the answer to the puzzle:

> Julia: Lilies, White, Wedding, Friday
>
> Amy: Daisies, Purple, Birthday, Wednesday
>
> Bethany: Tulips, Yellow, Backyard, Monday
>
> Rachel: Carnations, Peach, Office, Tuesday
>
> Kristen: Roses, Pink, Park, Thursday

Comment: You are saying that `has(f(bethany,_,_,backyard,_),F)` & `has(f(bethany,_,_,_,park,_),F)` must succeed - both.

Comment: Do not mutilate your question to one-liner, especially if has been solved. (I don't understand why Stackoverflow has no "rollback" action on the last edit. How does that make sense? It's probably a UI failure and should say "rollback to" instead of the implied "rollback this")

Comment: @DavidTonhofer you're right, the text *is* confusing. it does mean "roll back *to this*".

Comment: `has(X,F):- functor( F, flowers, 5), arg( _, F, X).`. you could even omit the first goal in the body if you start your `solve/1` with `F = flowers(A,B,C,D,E),` as you indeed do. then, `before(X,Y,F) :- arg( I, F, X), arg( J, F, Y), I < J.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `before/3` predicate was trying to deal with `flowers(A,B,C,D,E)` as if it were a list. It was always failing. You would need to define it as `[A,B,C,D,E]` for it to work.

It's actually better if you change `flowers(A,B,C,D,E)` to `[A,B,C,D,E]` so that you can use the built-in predicate `member/2` instead of `has/2`.

So, to start with I did this:

```
writeln(X) :- write(X), nl.

writelist([]).
writelist([H|T]) :- writeln(H), writelist(T).

/*Defines that X occurs on an earlier day than Y */
before(X,Y,F) :- append(F0, F1, F), member(X, F0), member(Y, F1).
```

You were also trying to say that bethany in in the backyard and the park. It needed to be an `or` relation.

Here's my version of `solve/1`:

```
solve(F) :-
/*clue 1 */
    F = [
        f(_,tulips,yellow,_,monday),
        f(_,_,_,office,tuesday),
        f(_,_,purple,_,wednesday),
        f(_,roses,_,park,thursday),
        f(julia,_,white,_,friday)
    ],
/* Clue 2 --> Look @ clue 3, Bethany can only have flowers in backyard or park */
    (member(f(bethany,_,_,backyard,_),F);
        member(f(bethany,_,_,_,park,_),F)),
/* Clue #4, Amy before Kristen, Rachel before Amy */
    before(f(amy,_,_,_,_),f(kristen,_,_,_,_),F),
    before(f(rachel,_,_,_,_),f(amy,_,_,_,_),F),
/* Clue #5 */
    member(f(rachel,_,peach,office,_),F),
/* Clue #6 */
    member(f(_,daisies,purple,_,wednesday),F),
/* Clue #7, pink before lillies, carnations before pink */
    before(f(_,_,pink,_,_),f(_,lilies,_,_,_),F),
    before(f(_,carnations,_,_,_),f(_,_,pink,_,_),F),
/* Clue #8 */
    before(f(_,_,_,birthday,_),f(_,_,_,wedding,_),F),
    before(f(_,_,_,office,_),f(_,_,_,birthday,_),F),
    true.
```

Now when I query `?- solve(F), writelist(F).` I get this:

```
f(bethany, tulips, yellow, backyard, monday)
f(rachel, carnations, peach, office, tuesday)
f(amy, daisies, purple, birthday, wednesday)
f(kristen, roses, pink, park, thursday)
f(julia, lilies, white, wedding, friday)
Yes.
```